# Spark 2.0.1 java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm starting playing with Spark 2.0.1. New Dataset API is very clean, but I'm having problems with very simple operations.

Maybe I'm missing something, hope somebody can help.

These instructions

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("local[*]");
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .config(conf)
        .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Info> infos = spark.read().json("data.json").as(Encoders.bean(Info.class));

System.out.println(infos.rdd().count());
```

produce a

```
 java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

and a fatal error detected by the JVM (1.8).

Working on the data using dataset api (i.e, selects, count on infos object) works fine.

How can I switch between Dataset and RDD?

Answer (score 7):

In general this error comes [when an application tries to create an array with negative size.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NegativeArraySizeException.html) see below example.

Its general java error. In your case I doubt this was caused by

```
 Dataset<Info> infos = spark.read().json("data.json").as(Encoders.bean(Info.class));

System.out.println(infos.rdd().count());
```

you could review this code in which scenario, its negetively initializing, by printing complete stack trace.

```java
~/
❯ cat StackTest.java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StackTest {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
        int c[]=new int[-2];
        Scanner in=new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int b=in.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[b];
    }
}

~/
❯ javac StackTest.java && java StackTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -2
        at StackTest.main(StackTest.java:6)
```

---

> **Note:**  One of the use case is using [`Kryo`](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/README.md) serialization along with
> apache spark... when it can happen/fix is like below...
>
> [Very large object graphs](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/README.md#very-large-object-graphs)
>
> Reference limits
>
> `Kryo` stores references in a map that is based on an `int` array.
> Since Java array indices are limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`,
> serializing large (> 1 billion) objects may result in a
> `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException`.
>
> A workaround for this issue is disabling Kryo's reference tracking as
> indicated below:
>
> ```
>   Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
>   kryo.setReferences(false);
> ```

or else a property like `spark.kryo.refferenceTrackingEnabled`=`false` in `spark-default.conf` or `sparkConf` object if you want to set it programatically..

[Spark docs says that](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization)

`spark.kryo.referenceTracking`  default value `true`

> Whether to track references to the same object when serializing data
> with Kryo, which is necessary if your object graphs have loops and
> useful for efficiency if they contain multiple copies of the same
> object. Can be disabled to improve performance if you know this is not
> the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is that spark.read() and other instructions are library calls, ie I have just used the library, without custom code, except for Info.class.

Comment: can you paste more details like your json, complete error stack trace  and Info model object etc...

Comment: According to [Spark Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) the setting from answer above in `spark-default.conf` is now called `spark.kryo.referenceTracking`.